# Entries of matrices of a complex representation of a finite group are all algebraic in some basis

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, diagonalization

More specifically, let $G$ be a finite group and $\pi$ a complex representation of $G$ in $V=\Bbb{C}^n$. Then we can choose a basis of $V=\Bbb{C}^n$ s.t. if we write $\pi$'s operators in matrix form by this basis as $\pi(g)=(\pi_{ij}(g))_{i,j\leq n}$, then there exists a finite extension $\Bbb{Q}\subseteq K$ s.t. $\pi_{ij}(g) \in F$ for all $i,j,g$.
Here is my take:

For $g\in G$ let $A=\pi(g)$ then if $|G|=m$ then $A^m=I$. Hence $A$'s minimal polynomial divides $x^m-1$ and since we are in $\Bbb{C}$ the polynomial $x^m-1$ has no double roots. From here $A$'s minimal polynomial splits into distinct linear factors hence $A$ is diagonalizable and all of its eigenvalues are roots of unity. So there exists a basis of $V$ s.t. the transformation $v\mapsto Av$ is represented by a matrix with entries in $K=\Bbb{Q}(e^{\frac{2i\pi}{m}})$.

Now, we have proved that for each $g\in G $ it is possible to find a basis s.t. $\pi(g)$ is represented as a matrix with entries in $K$. Here I am stuck, I know that every $g\in G$ has a basis s.t. $\pi(g)$ in that basis is represented by a matrix with entries in $K$ and that $K$ does not depend on the $g\in G$ we choose. The problem is finding a basis of $V$ s.t. *all* of $\pi$'s operators are represented as matrices with operators in $K$.

Any help is welcome

Comment: Use the spinning algorithm: Take a (nonzero, can be random) vector and calculate images under the group, adding vectors if they are linearly independent. Since the group is finite this terminates. If you don't get the full space pick another seed vector. Finiteness of the group means that matrix entries wrt the basis must be algebraic.